# Unable to Embed Apache Superset in my react App

Tags: reactjs, docker, apache-superset

I am trying to embed Apache Superset in my react app, currently, I have set it up on my local machine by following https://hub.docker.com/r/apache/superset guide. How can I go about from here, I tried following other tutorials but I don't see embed link option on my dashboard. Also how can I use it in production. [image: picture of my dashboard screen on localhost]

Answer (score 2):

In your `superset_config.py` file, add the following:

```
FEATURE_FLAGS = {
    "EMBEDDED_SUPERSET": True
}
```

Then re-run and verify.

Comment: Where can I find the configuration file, I have setup apache superset using docker.

Answer (score 0):

Sure you can Go to the docker UI : Container > Click on image > Files > app > superset >  config.py
Thankyou

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).